# Difference between "Sate" and "Satiate"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences, vocabulary, nuance

I'm studying GRE vocabulary, and there are these two words "sate" and "satiate". I couldn't determine whether they are interchangeable or have nuance. As a foreigner I really couldn't tell. Can somebody explain a little bit? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you do any independent research? I mean, I hate to sound rude, but if you google "define satiate", it literally brings up "another term for sate".

Comment: Yes, I did. And I looked up in the dictionary too. I hate to be rude but Im just not that open-my-mouth-and-ask kinda person. It's easy to look up the dictionary and usage for both words, but it's not easy for us to tell whether there is or isn't a difference in shades or usage especially for people who don't grow up in a English speaking country. And since I couldn't find comparison by another person online, that's why I post here.

Comment: @AleksandrH and also, words with same definition or synonyms sometimes do have nuance that you can't simply get from the dictionary.

Comment: Right, I understand, but "another term for sate" can't be interpreted in any other way.

Comment: @Elvin You should [edit] your question to indicate that you did this research (including the name of the dictionary), as it is one of the requirements here. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of our guidelines.

Comment: These graphs may be of interest:  [sated vs satiated](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sated%2Csatiated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csatiated%3B%2Cc0) and [sate vs satiate](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sate%2Csatiate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csatiate%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I actually think there is a sublte difference in when you would use one over the other even though I agree they mean the same thing.  It might have more to do with the final state of "satiation" and where the process of "getting sated" would favor satiating while the act at a definite time would favor sated.  But.. seems like people will not agree with me at all on that .. so perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: I think this is actually a good question. There are subtle differences between how they are used. Probably because "satiate" has the explicit verbal ending "ate" so it feels more transitive. However, it is never incorrect to use one in place of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're synonyms. I don't think there's a shade of difference between them.